# A group is solvable, Why we call it solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just learned the definition of solvable group from my algebra class, and I am curious why people call it "solvable" in terms of English and Mathematical meaning?
Is this term from the concept of polynomial or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the Abel-Ruffini theorem in Galois theory (I suspect you haven't gotten there yet). Basically, to each polynomial equation with coefficients in a given field we assign a group in a certain way (called the Galois group), and the theorem says that the equation is solvable using radicals iff the Galois group is solvable.

For instance, over the real numbers, the Galois group corresponding to $x^2+1=0$ is the group generated by complex conjugation, which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$. The group $\Bbb Z_2$ is abelian and solvable, so $x^2+1=0$ is solvable.

(In fact, over $\Bbb R$, the only Galois group you can have is that $\Bbb Z_2$; the theory gets interesting if you instead consider $\Bbb Q$, where for instance it is still an open problem whether any finite group appears as a Galois group, or the various finite fields.)